# Content page must be change without refreshing the master page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

We have a Master page with main menu's and sub menu's.If we click on main menu the corresponding sub menu's should be display after we click on sub menu's the content page should change without refreshing the master page.

Comment: You can change content of the page using Ajax you cannot call another page and keep master as it is, because master page is part of every page but maintained as a template

Comment: Can v call a content page without having master page layout??

Comment: No way, that's what I am saying there are no two pages it's only one page and part of header is maintained separately

Comment: How to change the sub-menu's by click on the main menu without refreshing the page using ajax?

Comment: You need to show menu code

Comment: <div id="menu_main"><ul><li id="menu_1" class="menu1" onclick="show()"><a href="#"></a></li>
<li id="menu_2" class="menu2" onclick="show1()"><a href="#"></a></li></ul></div> </div><div class="master-top-hline"></div><div class="master-leftpane"><div class="leftmenupane"><div id="div1">
<div  class="leftmenutitle">Procurement</div><div id="leftmenu1" style="height:100%; text-align:center!important">
                               <nav id="menu"> <ul>
                             <li><a href="WebForm1.aspx" >Menu1</a></li><li><a href="WebForm2.aspx">Menu1</a></li>
 </ul> </nav></div></div>

Comment: the onclick event is client side right why page will refresh?

Answer (score 0):

Yes It possible easily.

You can use IFrame to open content page. put your iframe on master page and create your menu like 
    **a href="http://www.microsoft.com" target="IFrame">Link Text**

Let me know if this will not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

you could put submenus into separate user controls. put a submenu in an update panel and change it when the main menu is clicked. the main menu can be the trigger for the update panel.

Comment: Can you please give more details?

Answer (score 0):

Add IFrame above content placeholder in master page

```
<iframe height="100%" width="100%"  name="iframe_a"> 
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                     </iframe>
```